# Visual studio reopen editor after debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I started debugging (some C# MVC application) and a lot of windows pop-up. So I closed all of them. But I probably change something.

Now when I have open some files in editor and press Debugging - it close them. After Stop debugging they are still closed. When I try to double-click on file in Solution explorer - nothing happen. Right click and Open - nothing. Only when right-click - Open with... and select another editor, it will open. Sometimes it ask that file is already open and if I want to close him. So it is probably open somewhere.

Any ideas how to fix it? I tried reset all setting, imported old environment, restarted Visual Studio and also computer and nothing helped.

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so finally I installed new VS 2015 and everything works as normal

Answer (score 0):

You can try to **Reset Window Layout** from the main **Window** menu in normal and debug modes.

Comment: unfortunately still a same